# Angular counting items on sublevel array

Tags: javascript, arrays, angularjs

I'm new to Angular, so I don't know how to do this, what I want is to count all results of a filtered array, but the problem is that data I want to filter is on second level array, I have seen some things on Stack Overflow but none of them seem to work. So basically I have this:

```
app.controller('mainController', function ($scope, $http, $location, $filter) {

    var externalOrigin1 = [];
    var externalOrigin2 = [];
    var externalOrigin3 = [];
    var externalOrigin4 = [];

    $http.get('app/data.json').then(function (datos) {
        externalOrigin1 = datos.data;
        externalOrigin2 = datos.data;//This will later be different on each case, but array will have same structure
        externalOrigin3 = datos.data;
        externalOrigin4 = datos.data;

        //Estructura de representación de datos

        $scope.Headers = [
       {
           'headerTitle': 'Morning Taskforce',
           'headerLinkCode': 'TFC',
           'headerData': externalOrigin1
       },
       {
           'headerTitle': 'Op Taskforce',
           'headerLinkCode': 'opr',
           'headerData': externalOrigin2
       },
       {
           'headerTitle': 'SAM Taskforce',
           'headerLinkCode': 'sbgr',
           'headerData': externalOrigin3
       },
       {
           'headerTitle': 'Undefined Section Taskforce',
           'headerLinkCode': 'ufts',
           'headerData': externalOrigin4
       }
        ];

        //Count all rows where ActionTaken is 'PENDING' on it, but this won't work

        $scope.pendingCount = $filter('pendingFilter')($scope.Headers.headerData, { autr: 'PENDING' }).length;
    });
});
```

Data on data.Json has this structure

```
[
  {
    "_id": "569fd9c251f51d316e12efbe",
    "actionTaken": "PENDING",
    "actionTakenCode": "P",
    "autr": false,
    "action": "CANCELAR",
    "actionAvailCode": "A",
    "tp": "male",
    "cta": 45.558392,
    "doc": 25.395304,
    "offset": 68305.2342,
    "client": "George Oneil",
    "terminal": 9215.6905
  },
  {
    "_id": "569fd9c27e048c82ce0564a4",
    "actionTaken": "CANCELED",
    "actionTakenCode": "C",
    "autr": false,
    "action": "AUTORIZAR",
    "actionAvailCode": "A",
    "tp": "male",
    "cta": 87.114735,
    "doc": -142.965417,
    "offset": 827448.2097,
    "client": "Fischer Ballard",
    "terminal": 2654.5002
  }
]
```

And on my view I have this:

```
 <ul data-role="listview" ng-repeat="header in Headers">
                <li data-role="list-divider" data-theme="a"><h2>{{header.headerTitle}}</h2></li>
                <li>
                    <table data-role="table" class="ui-grid-b ui-responsive table-stroke">
                        <thead>
                            <tr>
                                <th>
                                    ACT TAKEN
                                </th>
                                <th>
                                    OWNER
                                </th>
                                <th>
                                    TP
                                </th>
                                <th>
                                    CT
                                </th>
                                <th>
                                    DOCEMER
                                </th>
                                <th>
                                    MF47
                                </th>
                                <th>
                                    CLIENT
                                </th>
                                <th>
                                    BUREUS
                                </th>
                            </tr>
                        </thead>
                        <tbody>
                            <tr ng-repeat="dato in header.headerData | orderBy: '-monto'">
                                <td>
                                    <span class="indicator action-{{dato.actionTakenCode}}">{{dato.actionTaken}}</span>
                                </td>
                                <td>
                                    {{dato.autr}}
                                </td>
                                <td>
                                    {{dato.tp}}
                                </td>
                                <td>
                                    {{dato.cta}}
                                </td>
                                <td>
                                    {{dato.doc}}
                                </td>
                                <td>
                                    <b>{{dato.offset}}</b>
                                </td>
                                <td>
                                    {{dato.cliente}}
                                </td>
                                <td>
                                    {{dato.terminal}}
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                        </tbody>
                    </table>
                </li>
            </ul>
```

So far this do creates a table for every header, and rows for data on the sub level arrays, but I want to have an additional field that counts all PENDING on all tables, which I tried getting on pendingCount variable, but won't work.

```
<div id="overview">PENDING OPERATORS = {{pendingCount}} </div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to define pendingCount as a variable in $scope. Another way is to define a function in $scope called getPendingCount and do the math in that function. Let me know if I did not understand the context clearly and I'll try to help you out with this problem.

Also take a look at the documentation for $filter as the second parameter must be an array.

https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/filter

Iterate over the Headers array and call the filter for each one of them and sum up the quantity.

Another approach would be to just use 2 for statements and count the records that match your criteria.

Comment: I set "$scope.pendingCount =..." but the thing is I can't filter the sub level array, as you can see Headers array has a sub-level array inside headerData, that's the array I'm trying to target and filter

Comment: I will try it, I wanted to know if angular $filter could work on sublevel arrays

Comment: I don't think so because you cannot get an array using the array property like in $scope.Headers.headerData. You need to iterate over Headers and then call it for each Header object.